# How and where to execute the python bulkloader command to upload .CSV file to Google App engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

How and where to execute the python bulkloader command to upload a .CSV file to Google App engine ?

I am trying to upload a simple CSV file (2 column: tag, value, 7000 
lines) into my datastore google app engine using the bulkloader. 
I read the topic at: http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

I added to the app.yaml file :
  builtins: 
  - remote_api: on

Then I tried to execute the python command "create_bulkloader_config -- filename=bulkloader.yaml" , but I don’t know where to put it:
=> In python command line ? 
=> In Python IDLE ?
=> In Command.exe windows ?
=> elsewhere ?

Then, where do I get the file bulkloader.yaml" generated ? 
=> on my local disc ? on the api remote path ? how to catch it ?

This is certainly basic questions but I am not a python programmer, I 
need a step by step explanation to set my environment.

I used Google app engine launcher, Python 2.5 on Windows.

I set up a customtinywebdb service using the code provided at 
http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/reference/other/tinywebdb.html

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance ! (I am blocked at this point of my development).

Answer (score 2):

I run it from the command line, in the same directory as the app.yaml of my project.

Since appcfg.py is on my system path I can use the following command on MacOS (including the trailing dot):
`appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml .`

Then the bulkloader.yaml will be created in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `python -O appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml`? I would expect that, run in the folder that contains `appcfg.py` to create `bulkloader.yaml` in that same directory.